# How to add "a.csv" file to the existing Excel File "b.xlsx" as a new sheet with csv file name as Sheet name in Python?

Tags: python, excel

Have got a "a.csv" as output in Python and need to add that "a.csv" file to the already existing Excel File "b.xlsx" as a new Sheet to it with sheet name same as the .csv file name. How this could be done in Python?

Thanks is Advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read the **csv** into **dataframe** and write it into **excel**. Refer the below code.

```
import pandas as pd
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('b.xlsx')
pd.read_csv('a.csv').to_excel(writer,'sheetx')
writer.save()
```

Comment: Thank You for your help @satyma! The above code works partially by adding csv data to excel but  deletes the other sheets in the existing Excel and adds "a.csv" alone. The purpose is to add "a.csv" as another sheet along with the other existing sheets with data.

Comment: Adding this snippet before the above code solves the need.  
`from openpyxl import load_workbook
file = "b.xlsx"
book = load_workbook(file)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file, engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book`  Thank You!